# Change users apex oracle maintained = 'N' to 'Y'

Tags: oracle-apex

I got a db oracle 18.3, with the users apex oracle_maintained = 'N' and I want to make them oracle_maintained = 'Y'.
Given this condition,privileges and attributes have been modified in these schemas, so I seek that no user can alter them again.
I have productive applications on this installation,
I'm trying to determine the impact of this change.
As the only alternative, I found to delete the apex users and recreate them.

Did someone do something similar?
It's Apex 19.2.

Comment: It would be extremely dangerous to change how Oracle defines core  application user IDs such as `apex`.

Comment: Yes, I have received the database in this state. With user apex oracle_maintained = N.

It is a db 11g migrated to 18.3.
I already received it with these values ​​changed.

For security, I seek to take it as oracle_maintained = 'Y'.
To be the same as installations from 12c.

Thanks mark